# Как защитить файл от фиксации изменений?

Tags: git

Я работаю с системой GIT, и заметил, что использую некий паттерн, который хотел бы немного оптимизировать чтобы избежать ошибок в дальнейшем. Например у меня имеется некоторый файл настроек `Settings.h`, который мне требуется изменить на некоторый период моей работы. После окончания работы я хочу откатить изменения в этом файле, и я хочу найти способ, чтобы предотвратить себя от случайной фиксации изменений в этом файле (может конечно звучит немного странно, я понимаю что перед фиксацией изменений нужно постоянно следить за тем, что коммитишь, просто интересно может есть какой нибудь способ облегчить немного этот способ)

Comment: Может быть проще иметь debug локальный файлик не заливаемый в гит, но из которого будут браться настройки?.... типа если среда debug - работает тот файл, если prod - боевой

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, наверное такой файл должен быть отслеживаемым для изменений

Comment: ...эм....Зачем? весь смысл в том чтоб его иметь на локале и не заливать никуда, даже в репо

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да, я не так понял ваш комментарий, насколько я понимаю, этот файл будет влиять на целую сборку проекта? под файлом настроек я имел ввиду некоторый header который влияет на сборку проекта

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43940239/4928642

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/178988

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавить предкоммитный хук, который будет проверять, какие файлы изменены и реджектить комит в случае чего. Этот вариант вполне подходит для одного разработчика, чтобы другие могли спокойно коммитить этот файл.

Comment: Спасибо, я забыл о хуках (ими пользоваться пока не приходилось) Именно такой же ответ получил на англоязычном сайте (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940239/how-to-prevent-file-from-commiting-in-git)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, удалил часть про gitignore.

Comment: @Qwertiy теперь плюс )